I would like to know if itext leaves a log type on the machine when the commercial license is used
I have a question as to whether Itext 7 leaves any records of its consumption, I use the commercial license and I would like to know if itext leaves a log of its consumption on my machine and if so, where can I find it.
I hope you can help me with that question.

No, it does not make logs like that.  The best you can get is reading the meta data on the PDF files and it might have a tag for something like "PDF Producer" if that can be of use to you somehow.

if you are unable to remotely report your Volume, then a mechanism does exist to record the Volume locally on the server. You can either this route, or implement an interface to do it yourself.
